# Beamer transitions

Tags: beamer

I am making a presentation in beamer and I would like to make disappear and appear some images. I am using the option \only<> but I obtain different slides like:

[image]

[image]

When I click on the ouse button it seems like I am chaning the full slides instead of only the figures appearing.

The code is :

```
\begin{frame}
\centering
\textbf{Noise effect}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $y_1(t)=\cos(2\pi f_1 t)$
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.14]{sineseriesspectrum}\\
    \only<1>{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{noiseeffectsine}}
    %\transfade{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{noiseeffectsine}}
    \only<2>{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{sineeffectresults}}
\end{itemize}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $y_2(t)=\text{white noise}$
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.14]{wnseriesspectrum}\\
    \only<1>{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{noiseeffectwn}}
    \only<2>{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{noiseeffectresults}}
\end{itemize}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148/avoiding-jumping-frames-in-beamer to avoid the items jump around. Would you agree?

Comment: I read the answers but no solutions has helped me....

Comment: @Jonel_R: Does [Get a includegraphic to stick in the same place for several beamer slides](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82369/13304) help?

Comment: The description of what you are trying to achieve is not clear to me. Seeing your code, you have 7 images; for commodity, let's call them `ima1`,...,`ima7`. How exactly do you want the images to appear/disappear?

Answer (score 1):

Based on OP's code, there are a total of 6 images to be shown in a two-columns format (side by side). It seems that the OP wants images in row 2(bin location) and row 3(tables) to show up in the same frame via 2 slides. If the observation is correct, `\alt<2>{image1}{image2}` should be used instead of \only<1> and \only<2> because <2> does not replace the <1>.

[image]
[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\textbf{Noise effect}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $y_1(t)=\cos(2\pi f_1 t)$
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.14]{abc}\\
    \alt<2>{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{penguin}}
    %\transfade{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{noiseeffectsine}}
    {\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{lion}}
\end{itemize}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $y_2(t)=\text{white noise}$
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.14]{abc}\\
    \alt<2>{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{penguin}}
    {\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{lion}}
\end{itemize}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```