# Add many graphics to stick in the same place for several beamer slides in TexLive 2023

Tags: beamer, overlays, includegraphics

For this I tried to use the following code [from this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82372/241755) But the images are shifted by almost one character in each new slide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe,lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.65\textwidth}
\includegraphics<1>[scale=0.6]{example-image}
\includegraphics<2>[scale=0.6]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics<3>[scale=0.6]{example-image-b}
\includegraphics<4>[scale=0.6]{example-image-c}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{overprint}
\only<1>{This is the text explaining picture 1}\only<2>{This is the text explaining picture a}\only<3>{This is the text explaining picture b}\only<4>{This is the text explaining picture c}
\end{overprint}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are adding spaces between the images.

Comment: Add a `%` at the end of the`\includegraphics...` lines to remove the implicit space.

Comment: (the `%` were not yet necessary in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82372/241755 because back then beamer did not yet treat line endings as spaces)

Comment: Thanks to all. Has been fixed!